# Count in foreach loop by same model and condition

Tags: php, foreach

I would like to get the count (total) of values in my foreach loop which share the same 'Model' and 'Condtion'.

To help you understand better, here is a representation of how my data looks like

```
 Product Name            |    Condition
 ---------------------------------------
 iPhone 3G 16GB          |    Used

 iPhone 3G 16GB          |    Used

 iPhone 3G 16GB          |    New

 Blackberry 9900         |    New

 Blackberry 9900         |    New
```

**My current foreach loop:-**

```
 $results = getProducts();

 foreach ($results as $result) {

 $data[] = array (
'model' => $result['model'],
'condition' => $result['condition']
 );  
}
```

**This is what I get with my current foreach loop:-**

```
 Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [model] => iPhone 3G 16GB
        [condition] => Used
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [model] => iPhone 3G 16GB
        [condition] => Used
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [model] => iPhone 3G 16GB
        [condition] => New
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [model] => Blackberry 9900
        [condition] => New
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [model] => Blackberry 9900
        [condition] => New
    )
)
```

**Here is how and what I would like to get instead:-**

```
 Array(
 'Apple iPhone 3G 16GB' => Array (
 'Used' => 2,
 'New' => 1
 )
 'Blackberry 9900' => Array (
 'New' => 2 
 )
)
```

Hope you get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish here. Please let me know if you would like me to provide any additional info.

Comment: It makes more sense to do this on the SQL level.

Comment: @Jonast92 thanks for your suggestion and tbh I do have a solution to do this on SQL level while fetching results but I would like to know if it's possible in PHP only or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the desired result.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if (!array_key_exists($result['model'], $data)) {
        $data[ $result['model'] ] = array(
            'Used' => 0,
            'New' => 0
        );
    }
    $data[ $result['model'] ][ $result['condition'] ]++;
}
```

Keep in mind that alphabetical indices are **case sensitive** in PHP, so you might want to add a `strtolower()` to avoid undefined index notices.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array(
    array('model' => 'Apple iPhone 3G 16GB', 'condition' => 'used'),
    array('model' => 'Apple iPhone 3G 16GB', 'condition' => 'used'),
    array('model' => 'Apple iPhone 3G 16GB', 'condition' => 'new'),
    array('model' => 'Blackberry 9900', 'condition' => 'new'),
    array('model' => 'Apple iPhone 3G 16GB', 'condition' => 'new'),
    array('model' => 'Blackberry 9900', 'condition' => 'used')
);

$data = array();

foreach($results as $result) {
    $model = $result['model'];
    $condition = $result['condition'];
    if(array_key_exists($model, $data)) {
        $data[$model][$condition]++;
        continue;
    }
    $data[$model][$condition] = 1;
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried out your solution and it works as well.

Comment: Try it with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and you will get an undefined index notice